# Linux + OpenVPN; bridge interface not responding to ARP

Tags: linux, openvpn, bridge, tap

I am trying to set up an OpenVPN connection with a Layer2 ethernet bridge to bridge two LANs. ARP responses do not seem to being generated correctly...

Please note I want to create a *full* Layer2 bridge, so that all traffic, including broadcast packets, can be relayed. I will use ebtables and other methods to block DHCP, etc.

## Netork Topology

We have two LANs (we'll call them LAN1 and LAN2) at different physical locations. Each LAN is a standard residential network on a consumer-grade internet connection.

> ```
> ------------     ---------     ----------    ------------------------
> * Internet * --> * Modem * --> * Router * -> * Switches and Clients *
> ------------     ---------     ----------    ------------------------
> ```

On each network, we've built a Linux server, designed to act as a backup fileserver and VPN bridge. The servers, called Thing1 (on LAN1) and Thing2 (on LAN2) are client devices.

LAN1 uses 192.168.110.0/24

- Router1 (ASUS RT-AC68U) as DHCP server and internet gateway at 192.168.110.254
- Various switches and client PCs, phones, TVs, etc.
- Thing1 (OpenVPN server) connected at 192.168.110.250

LAN2 uses 192.168.111.0/24

- Router2 (ASUS RT-AC66U) as DHCP server and internet gateway at 192.168.111.254
- Various switches and client PCs, phones, TVs, etc.
- Thing2 (OpenVPN server) connected at 192.168.111.250

## Configuration

Each of the OpenVPN machines (Thing1 and Thing2) has OpenVPN installed and running. The connection has been created successfully.

On each server, we create our tap and bridge using a bridge-start script. I've trimmed it here...

### bridge-start

> ```
> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
> br="br0"
> tap="tap0"
> eth="enp2s0"
>
> #obtain the Hardware Mac address of the physical ethernet interface
> eth_hw_mac=`ifconfig $eth | grep 'HWaddr' | cut -d' ' -f9`
>
> for t in $tap; do
>     ip tuntap add dev $t mode tap
> done
>
> brctl addbr $br
> brctl addif $br $eth
>
> for t in $tap; do
>     brctl addif $br $t
> done
>
> for t in $tap; do
>     ifconfig $t 0.0.0.0 promisc up
> done
>
> ifconfig $eth 0.0.0.0 promisc up
> ifconfig $br hw ether $eth_hw_mac
>
> dhclient $br
>
> # Load ebtables rules to block DHCP traffic across the bridge.
> ebtables -A INPUT -i tap0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto udp --ip-dport 67:68 -j DROP
> ebtables -A INPUT -i tap0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto udp --ip-sport 67:68 -j DROP
> ebtables -A FORWARD -o tap0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto udp --ip-dport 67:68 -j DROP
> ebtables -A FORWARD -o tap0 -p ipv4 --ip-proto udp --ip-sport 67:68 -j DROP
> ```

The only difference is that on Thing2, the tap interface is named tap1, rather than tap0.

### Relevant ifconfig on Thing1 (192.168.110.250)

> ```
> br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f
>           inet addr:192.168.110.250  Bcast:192.168.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fefc:4a4f/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:560719 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:271873 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:120753983 (120.7 MB)  TX bytes:72273308 (72.2 MB)
>
> enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f
>           inet6 addr: fe80::baae:edff:fefc:4a4f/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:525244 errors:0 dropped:68 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:548223 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:142488031 (142.4 MB)  TX bytes:129824161 (129.8 MB)
>
> tap0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9
>           inet6 addr: fe80::c45d:10ff:fe17:5cb9/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:240521 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:238686 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
>           RX bytes:49398722 (49.3 MB)  TX bytes:47097224 (47.0 MB)
> ```

### Relevant ifconfig on Thing2 (192.168.111.250)

> ```
> br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:4d:30:08:f1:e5
>           inet addr:192.168.111.250  Bcast:192.168.111.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::f64d:30ff:fe08:f1e5/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:1049729 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:757240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:5142387727 (5.1 GB)  TX bytes:302576425 (302.5 MB)
>
> enp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:4d:30:08:f1:e5
>           inet6 addr: fe80::f64d:30ff:fe08:f1e5/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:7254547 errors:0 dropped:389 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:3661240 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
>           RX bytes:6092825279 (6.0 GB)  TX bytes:1214754910 (1.2 GB)
>
> tap1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2
>           inet addr:192.168.110.1  Bcast:192.168.110.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>           inet6 addr: fe80::446f:eeff:fe61:deb2/64 Scope:Link
>           UP BROADCAST RUNNING PROMISC MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>           RX packets:233278 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>           TX packets:294344 errors:0 dropped:46711 overruns:0 carrier:0
>           collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
>           RX bytes:46740438 (46.7 MB)  TX bytes:129353655 (129.3 MB)
> ```

### Relevant lines from OpenVPN server.conf on Thing1 (192.168.110.250)

> ```
> port 1194
> proto udp
> dev tap0
> topology subnet
> ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
> server-bridge 192.168.110.250 255.255.255.0 192.168.110.1 192.168.110.10
> client-to-client
> keepalive 10 120
> persist-key
> persist-tun
> ```

### Route table on Thing1

> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
> 192.168.110.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
> 192.168.111.0   192.168.111.250 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tap0
> 192.168.111.250 *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap0
> ```

### Route table on Thing2

> ```
> Kernel IP routing table
> Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
> default         router.asus.com 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
> 192.168.110.0   192.168.110.250 255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tap1
> 192.168.110.250 *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tap1
> 192.168.111.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
> ```

## Problem

I attempt to ping .111.250 from .110.250, but the ARP resolution never happens...

> ```
> ping 192.168.111.250
>
> PING 192.168.111.250 (192.168.111.250) 56(84) bytes of data.
> From 192.168.110.250 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
> From 192.168.110.250 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
> From 192.168.110.250 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
> ```

Doing a tcpdump on .110.250's tap while the ping is happening...

> ```
> tcpdump -i tap0 -en | grep "ARP"
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
> listening on tap0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
> 15:43:08.283935 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:43:08.300129 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:43:08.300181 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:43:09.300441 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:43:09.300493 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:43:10.302120 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:43:10.302170 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:43:11.300760 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:43:11.300810 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:43:12.300762 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:43:12.300815 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> ```

This sequence repeats for each ping attempt.

Meanwhile, on .111.250's tap1 (which has IP 192.168.110.1)...

> ```
> tcpdump -i tap1 -en | grep "ARP"
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
> listening on tap1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
> 15:49:47.315913 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:49:47.813360 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:49:47.830572 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:49:48.314726 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:49:48.812622 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.110.250 tell 192.168.110.1, length 28
> 15:49:48.832273 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> ```

If we look at .111.250's br0 (which actually has 192.168.111.250)...

> ```
> tcpdump -i br0 -en | grep "ARP"
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
> listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
> 15:53:49.969025 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:53:50.341753 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> 15:53:50.968877 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:53:51.341336 b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f > 46:6f:ee:61:de:b2, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.110.250 is-at b8:ae:ed:fc:4a:4f, length 28
> ```

But at the physical ethernet adapter...

> ```
> tcpdump -i enp2s0 -en | grep "ARP"
>
> tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
> listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
> 15:56:13.344685 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> 15:56:14.344167 c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.111.250 tell 192.168.110.250, length 28
> ```

As far as I understand, Thing2's br0, which has address 192.168.111.250 should be sending a reply something like...

> ```
> f4:4d:30:08:f1:e5 > c6:5d:10:17:5c:b9, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.111.250 is-at f4:4d:30:08:f1:e5, length 28
> ```

I don't know that this will fix everything that's broken, or if I'm missing something very obvious. Feel free to make any suggestions which you think would move me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are trying to bridge two different IP subnets, which does not work. One IP subnet consists of a single broadcast domain, and now you are trying to set up two different IP subnets in a single broadcast domain (bridge over the VPN).

What happens during the ping is that your `192.168.111.250` sends ARP request to `192.168.110.250`, which will not answer it because the request comes from an IP address outside of its subnet `192.168.110.0/24`.

Another issue in your configuration is that you have defined an IP address both to your `br0` device, which is the bridge device, and the `tapX` device, which is part of the bridge.

You should only assign an IP address to the bridge device.

You need to redesign your networking concept so that you use a single IP subnet over your bridge if you really want a full L2 networking solution.

Comment: In that case, would setting a /16 netmask on the bridges and taps alleviate the issue?

Comment: Yes, that would make it a single broadcast domain, covering all IP addresses from `192.168.0.0` to `192.168.255.255`. However, if the network would get this many devices in the end, it would not work reliably due to excessive broadcast traffic. You might want to use `/23` or `255.255.254.0` netmask, which covers `192.168.111.0` to `192.168.112.255`.